# Renaming war file after exporting from eclipse to hit web api

Tags: java, rest, asp.net-web-api, postman, war

I am trying to develop web api by java. I exported the war from eclipse by right click on the module and determine a destination. After that I changed the name of the war to avoid conflicting on the server with a previous war with the same name. Now, I am trying to hit the api using postman with the link ([WARFILENAME]/rest/[ClassPath]/[FunctionName]) but there is no response. My question is: is it correct to rename the war file after creating it? is there any other step to make the api working? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thing your question is not having all information!
If you are using servlet then the path will be `http://{host:port}/warFile/{uri-path-of-servlet}`

You can change the `warFile` name. The context of that app will be same as `warFile` in URL.

If you are new to J2EE then you can try this: https://javatutorial.net/servlet-annotation-example.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to make sure that I can change the war name. I am not using the servlet. I using the @path annotation, It is working now anyway.